# Export/Download Clickfunnels as HTML (including all assets)

Tags: html

I'm trying to download a a funnel in Clickfunnels as a whole assets. I know the typical step that Clickfunnel have in exporting HTML is through the Publishing option->Export as HTML
. But it don't include the whole code and assets used in front-end. Anybody have an idea to download the funnel including the images,fonts,css, html used? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can not download/export everything as HTML.